# Ubuntu 18: date lagging behind by ~17 seconds

Tags: 18.04, server, time, ntp

I have problems with time syncing in Ubuntu 18, this is my version, running on digital ocean:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bioni
```

When I write `date` I'll get `Sun Dec 29 15:24:50 UTC 2019`, but `sudo hwclock --show` gives `2019-12-29 15:25:06.699770+0000`. The hardware clock actually shows the correct time.

`timedatectl status` shows this information

```
Local time: Sun 2019-12-29 15:25:29 Universal time: Sun 2019-12-29 15:25:29 UTC
RTC time: Sun 2019-12-29 15:25:46
Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
```

So it seems that the clock is not syncronized. I've seen a lot of soultions involving installing `ntpdate` but it says here that this programs is depreciated:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html

After running

`systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` shows that the service is running.

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-12-28 23:28:33 UTC; 16h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 31580 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Idle."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─31580 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
```

I've tried to restart the service `sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd`

The status will just say `Status: "Connecting to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)."` for a few minutes before becoming idle.

I've tried to add other timeservers to `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`

```
...
# See timesyncd.conf(5) for details.

[Time]
#NTP=
#FallbackNTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

Uncommenting `#NTP=` and changing to  `NTP=time.google.com`, and restarting the service, but the time will still not sync.

I'm using a network firewall with no outbound rules:

[image: Firewall settings]

- Are there any error logs I can check why it's not connecting?
- Can I ping any other timeserver and see if it's responding?
- Is the key here to change NTP or fallback NTP?

Any help greatly appreciated, I'm really lost here :S

Comment: Can you ping `91.189.89.198`? And the protocol is UDP, not TCP. Are outbound UDP allowed?

Comment: @Pilot6 Omg thank you so much, adding allowing all outgoing UDP to the firewall fixed the problem.

Comment: @user1506145 You should probably allow UDP, ICMP and a few other protocols as well. Stopping these causes all kinds of weird problems.

Comment: @vidarlo these are the possible protocols: "All TCP", "All UDP", "SSH", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "MySQL", "DNS TCP", "DNS UDP", "ICMP", "Custom", "All TCP", "All UDP", "SSH", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "MySQL", "DNS TCP", "DNS UDP", "ICMP", "Custom". Should I add a rule for each of them and allow all outgoing IP:s and ports?

Comment: I would allow ICMP and UDP at least. Other protocols are somewhat more obscure, but things like PPTP uses GRE protocol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time sync protocol uses UDP, not TCP.

You need to allow UDP protocol in your firewall settings.